# Problem with math fonts in beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, math-fonts

I'm doing a presentation with beamer, and I need to change some specific characters to the usual math font. In particular, I need some "a"s to look like they are commonly written for creation and annihilation operators.

I don't want to change all the equations to math font but just the "a"s.

This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}      
  \usecolortheme{default} 
  \usefonttheme{default}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\title[]{TITLE}
\author[]{AUTHOR}
\institute{INSTITUTE}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Name}
     \[
      [a_i,a_j] = [a^*_i,a^*_j] = 0,\hspace{4em} [a_i,a^*_j]=\delta_{ij}\mathbb{1}
     \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `\mathrm{}` is what you want, I think.

Comment: Also, replace `\hspace{4em}` by `\quad` or `\qquad`.

Comment: `\mathrm{}` makes a different kind of "a", but it is not the rounded "a" I need.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you add the following two instructions to the preamble; you'll get the "rounded" or "single-storey" "a" glyphs while preserving the sans-serif look (which, I gather, you want to do).

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{arev}
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
  \usetheme{Madrid}      
  \usecolortheme{default} 
  \usefonttheme{default}  
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{arev}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Name}
     \[
      [a_i,a_j] = [a^*_i,a^*_j] = 0, 
      \qquad 
      [a_i^{},a^*_j]=\delta_{ij}\mathbb{1}
     \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but it also changes the rest of the text in other slides. Is there a way to change only an specific equation?

Comment: @TsuKi - Not really, at least if you use pdfLaTeX. Are you willing and able to use LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I don't really know what that is. I use sharelatex.

Comment: @TsuKi - If you use the sharelatex platform, I believe you're stuck with pdfLaTeX, at least for the foreseeable future.